# Special thing every hour from list

Tags: php

I have a list of dates in an array (in unix integer format).

I have sorted these numbers in ascending order.  Done.

Now, I am looping through every element using the foreach command.

I am trying to add a `echo '<p>';` every time the hour changes in the data...so I am trying to get a list of the dates, sorted, and with a `<p>` every hour so they are in hourly blocks...

How to do this?

Comment: Okay cool, and what is your question?

Comment: @OP - More information is needed to understand what you are trying to do. A sample of your data list, a sample of the code you have now, what's working, what's not working... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
//list of unix timestamps 
$timeStamps = array();
//false data for testing
for($i=1;$i<=30;$i++){
    $timeStamps[] = strtotime("+".($i*10)." minutes");
}

//remember the last value.
$new = '';
$last = '';
//loop through the timestamps
foreach($timeStamps as $ts){
    //generate a hour string for this ts
    $new = date('d-M-Y H', $ts);
    //if this hour string is not the same as the last hour string echo p tag
    if($new != $last){
        echo '<p>';
    }
    //set $last to the new hour string for next loop.
    $new = $last;

    //echo the date
    echo date('d-M-Y H:i', $ts).'<br />';
}
```

I also included the date in the hour string to prevent problems with the date changing. for example if a timestamp is for `1-NOV-2011 1:00am` and the next timestamp is for `2-NOV-2011 1:00am` just checking the hour will not echo a <p>. including the date will.

Comment: Ah! so simple.  I should have looked for a change rather than a hour-1, because then I was getting negatives.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Send your UNIX time into the php function date().  It will pass back a string that you should be able to notice when the hour changes.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I tried that, but when the day changes it stops working...

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but off the top of my head:

```
$currentHour = -1;
foreach ($dates as $date)
{
    $dateHour = intval(date('G'), $date);
    if ($currentHour != $dateHour)
    {
        echo '<p>';
    }
    if ($dateHour == $currentHour + 1)
    {
        echo '</p>';
    }
    $currentHour = $dateHour;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using Unix dates, but....

The answer should lie in simple math. An hour is a median. Unix timestamps start from January 1, 1970, 0000 hours.

Because Unix timestamps are seconds, you can find an hour by dividing the timestamp by 3600. If it's divisible, you're on an hour median.

You'll want to use the [modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) for this.

```
echo "<p>";
foreach ($unixtimes as $my_timestamp)
{
    if ($my_timestamp % 3600 == 0) echo "</p><p>"; // If there's no remainder, it's an hour.
    echo $my_timestamp;
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Syntax may not be correct, but the idea is sound. Also saves you doing date conversions. Best of luck.

Edit: Wrote the whole thing out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work! Good luck :)

```
foreach ( $timestamps as $timestamp )
{
    // Get the number of hours this timestamp represents starting Jan 1, 1970 (3600 are seconds in an hour)
    $currentHour = floor( $timestamp / 3600 );
    if ( $currentHour != $previousHour )
    {
        echo '<p>';

    // Add your logic here..

        $previousHour = $currentHour;
    }
}
```